# Div with overflow:auto, end reaches = start a function

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Scroll Position of div with “overflow: auto”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344615/javascript-scroll-position-of-div-with-overflow-auto)

Hi,
i want to start a function XXX(); when the scroll-end from a div (overflow:auto;) is reached.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:500px; overflow:auto;">
/* content here */
</div>
```

Is this possible?

greetz from germany
Peter

Comment: this is not a duplicate...he wants to know how to call a function at the end of a scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you add an extra `<div>` inside the `<div style="overflow: auto">`.  We then use this internal div to capture the height of the text.  This then allows us to us to check if scrolling is finished.  You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/D5uht/).

The code itself is below where `#parent` is the id I gave to the div in your example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parent = $('#parent');
    var text = $('<div id="text">').text(parent.text());
    parent.text('');
    parent.append(text);
});

$('#parent').scroll(function(){
    if(($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) == $('#text').height())
        alert('Done scrolling');
});
```