# Vertical Scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a div 400px x 400px which contains text that i need to scroll.  I would like to do it with control on a couple of arrow images (up and down). Can this be done with jquery?  I also dont want a scroller off to the side of the div.  just a couple up and down arrows under the div to control the scrolling of the content.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a very unpleasant thing to do to your users. If my scroll wheel doesn't work on your content, I'll be clicking away to another site.

Comment: Please please please stick to standard user interfaces. The way they look tells people that they work the same way that other controls that look that way work. They automatically provide mouse, keyboard, etc access.

Comment: I agree completely.  with both comments above.  A site was being built 100% in flash which im sure everyone can image was a bad idea. So im stuck with pulling as much out of flash as i can but keeping certain effects that the client liked.  One is this scrolling thing. If i cant convince otherwise i have  to pull this off not using flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be helpful: [Scroll Position of div with "overflow: auto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344615)

Don't even need to use jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. I did search but must not have been searching the right terms or not deep enough.  Thanks again.

Comment: First two links not has no data now. If you had some new reference please edit these links.

Comment: They look fine to me.

Comment: First two links are now dead, only the SO answer is left