# How to center an image in a div?

Tags: css, image, html

I´m displaying an images 1000x1000px in a smaller div 320x460px with overflow:auto so you can scroll the image within the div.
When I load the page then the image is displayed from the left-top corner off the image, and I wonder how I can display the image centered instead?

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code.
In my index file I load the page like this:

```
$('#kartamap').load('imagemap.html', function() {
                    alert(".load has loaded");  
                    imagescroll();                                                                     

                           });
```

And this is my page.

```
<div id="themap">

 <div id="imagediven" style="height:460px; width:320px;">

  <img src="image.png" width="1000px" height="1000px"/>

  </div>

<style>
#imagediven {
    overflow:auto;
    height:460px;
    width:320px;
    position:relative;
}

</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function imagescroll(){
    var element = document.getElementById('imagediven'), /* This is your div */
            scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight,
            scrollWidth = element.scrollWidth;
        clientHeight =$(window).height();
            clientWidth = $(window).width();

        alert(scrollHeight);//this is not displaying the image height?
        alert(clientHeight);//this is getting a value off the screen

    element.scrollTop = (scrollHeight - clientHeight) / 2;
    element.scrollLeft = (scrollWidth - clientWidth) / 2;
    }

    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Does the `div` contain anything else other then the image which you wish to center?

Comment: try text-align:center;

Comment: try to change position of <img> in style

Comment: Hi Matt, no just the image.

Comment: where is your code? post it here please.. right now every user here is guessing because you haven't provided the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to scroll the `div` to the center of the `img`.

You need to use Javascript properties `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`

For scrolling to the centre, you need to set the values as

```
scrollTop = (scrollHeight - clientHeight) / 2;
scrollLeft = (scrollWidth - clientWidth) / 2;
```

JS :

```
var element = document.getElementById('container'); /* This is your div */

element.scrollTop = (element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight) / 2;
element.scrollLeft = (element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth) / 2;
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/aH482/)

**Documentation :**
[scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop) |
[scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollLeft) |
[scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight) | 
[scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollWidth) |
[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight) | 
[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth)

Comment: Hi Nikhil and thanks a lot, it works perfect in fiddle but I can´t getting it to work in my web app? In my index file I load the map page with jquery.load but it is not scrolling the image?!

Comment: Check whether the scroll event is happening after the load, or before it. I'll suggest scrolling as a callback event after the load.

Comment: I´m testing different things, but even if I .load the page and in that page have a function that runs after the page is loaded and I set the scrollHeight to a fixed number, the element.scrollTop show up with 0 in an alert?

Comment: If you get the `scrollTop` value, i.e `alert(element.scrollTop)`, it'll display the current scroll value, which'll be `0` since the `div` is not scrolled. You don't have to set the `scrollHeight`, it's automatically calculated. Set the value of `scrollTop` instead.

Comment: I don´t know where I go wrong, but element.scrollHeight and width is not getting any value. So to test I thought that I would set some static numbers to test with.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - Your code is working on my end. Its alerting the values. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Ok, I´m not sure what was wrong, now if I load only that page it works right, but not when I load it in the app? Do you have time to look at my app? I can send you the link in an email, mine is info@manmade.se, I don´t want to put the link here. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Send at niks999[@]gmail.com. And I think this question is answered?

Answer (score 1):

you can assign 320px width and 460px height to the container div. Then apply 25% margin to your image in css...it will align your image in center from all sides.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="img">
 <img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
div#img
{
width:320px;
height:460px;
overflow:scroll;

}
div#img img{margin:0 auto;padding:0;margin:25%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be working with the same size image 100% of the time you could position it absolutely.

```
.className {
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
}
.className img {
  left: 50%;
  margin: -500px 0 0 -500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

I've worked this out on the image being 1000px x 1000px.

Also, I've put a jsFiddle together for you to view it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/7x2JR/

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it work good, but I will have different sizes of the images, so it´s not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `background-position` property.

You can also use `background-size: cover` (or contain) to make it fits your div.

Comment: Hi Rachid, I can´t use background, it has to be img.

Comment: Oh okay. How about a text-align center on the div that contains the image ?

Answer (score 0):

```
div img
{
margin:auto;
width:320px;
height:460px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but centering a bigger image in a smaller div is not the same as centering  a small image in a bigger div, it doesn´t work the same way.

Comment: now i got ur point..give padding:50px;overflow:hidden;..... It will give a space of 50 px from all the sides and scroll bar when overflow..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Thanks, but centering a bigger image in a smaller div is not the same as centering  a small image in a bigger div, it doesn´t work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think `scrollTop` is the property you are looking for, have a look at this SO question: [Scroll Position of div with "overflow: auto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344615/scroll-position-of-div-with-overflow-auto)

(Actually, you do not want to center the image within the div, but scroll the div to the center.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <div text-align:center">
    <img src="img.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: It's very obvious; try an HTML validator?