# Can't get horizontal Scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get horizontal scroll Position of my div and I can't get why this isn't working.

Here's [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/pgyQjw).

**HTML**

```
<div class='demo'>dsannbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.demo {
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(this).scrollLeft() >= 100){
         alert();   
    }
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('.demo');
    
    if(div.scrollLeft() >= 100){
         alert();   
    }
}); 

use your div instead of 'this'

maybe you can use this as your reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344615/scroll-position-of-div-with-overflow-auto

Comment: Do you want to check the scroll position on div?

Comment: @alirezasafian exactly

Comment: Check [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/GoZwNJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you code is doing, is it's getting the value of `scrollLeft()` when the document is ready (which is 0) and it never changes. You need an event to capture when the scroll of the `.demo` event is changing. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.demo').on('scroll', function() {
    var val = $(this).scrollLeft()
    if (val >= 100) alert('Hello')
  })
});
```

Comment: No prob, it takes some time getting used to the events.

Comment: Ok, but how would I go if I wanted this function to execute on load?