# How to get pageYOffset of a div?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I cannot get a div's `pageYOffset`.

I'm trying to get rid of the html scrollbar so that it only appears between toolbar and footer components instead of getting displayed over them.

**Here's an example**:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYppdQ

I made html overflow hidden and allowed only a content tag to be scrollable.

Most likely I'm doing something wrong there but `OffsetTop` stays at 0 when I'm trying to get the value using this method:

```
onScroll (e) {
  this.offsetTop = window.getElementsByClassName("scroll-container").pageYOffset
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Position of div with "overflow: auto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344615/scroll-position-of-div-with-overflow-auto)

Comment: i dont see a scrollbar *over* the footer/header, only in the content section

Comment: @Blauhirn yeah, that's the point, I only need it to be displayed between the toolbar and footer, but `pageYOffset` stops working when I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem does not lie in the `pageYOffset`. The `onScroll` method gets never executed at all. Try with something easier like `v-on:click="..."` first.

Also, `v-scroll` seems to rely on an external library which you havent included in the codepen.

Also also, you probably should not use `.getElementBy..blabla` but use Vue.js for that: `<div ref="myDiv">` and `this.offsetTop = this.$refs.myDiv.pageYOffset;`. But I dont think `pageYOffset` is a valid property of any dom node. There is only `window.pageYOffset`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

pageYOffset is a read-only window property that returns the number of pixels the document has been scrolled vertically. And scrollY is the exactly same thing.